# Why isn't $G=1$ as common as $c=\hbar=1$?

Tags: soft-question, units

It is standard practice in theoretical physics to use a system of units in which $c=\hbar=1$. However, even though you *could* also set $G=1$, most physicists prefer not to. For example, in my cosmology textbooks, they readily do away with $c$, but decide to keep $G$ explicitly in e.g. the Friedmann equation.

Why is this common practice?

Comment: It's typically nice to keep *some* dimensionful parameter around, to be able to do dimensional analysis.

Comment: $G=1$ is standard practice in numerical relativity.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrized_unit_system (But: "The geometrized unit system, used in general relativity, is not a completely defined system.")